# How to disable inline CSS in Gatsby?

Tags: css, gatsby

I created a website with [gatsby-starter-ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost).

I noticed that by default the CSS is put into the head of every HTML file as an inline style:

```
<style>.every-thing-is-in-here {}</style>
```

I want to serve the CSS in its own file and not alongside every HTML file.

How can I disable this behaviour and use `<link>` for CSS instead?

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/global-css/#adding-global-styles-without-a-layout-component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this is not configurable. I found a solution on [Github](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1526#issuecomment-433347822). Basically in your `gatsby-ssr.js` rewrite the `style` elements like this:

```js
export const onPreRenderHTML = ({getHeadComponents}) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')
        return

    getHeadComponents().forEach(el => {
        // Remove inline css.
        if (el.type === 'style') {
            el.type = 'link'
            el.props['href'] = el.props['data-href']
            el.props['rel'] = 'stylesheet'
            el.props['type'] = 'text/css'

            delete el.props['data-href']
            delete el.props['dangerouslySetInnerHTML']
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It's worth checking that there is a value in `el.props['data-href']` before doing the transformation, to avoid affecting custom style tags for example. You can do this by replacing line 7 with `if (el.type === 'style' && el.props['data-href'])`